# Date Validation between start date and end date in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validation, date, range

I am doing a program to filter data between two dates, Starting date and End Date. In my controller I have this :

```
 public ActionResult List(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate)
        {


            if (enddate < startdate)
            {

                return PartialView("DateValidation");
            }
            else
            {
                List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();

                using (var db = new CardDBEntities())
                {

                    var cardr = (from c in db.Cards
                                 join d in db.RegistrationDTs
                                 on c.CardId equals d.CardId
                                 where d.RegistrationDateTime >= startdate &&
                                       d.RegistrationDateTime <= enddate
                                 select new eReader1.Models.Model
                                 {
                                     CardId = d.CardId,
                                     Description = c.Description,
                                     RegistrationDateTime = d.RegistrationDateTime
                                 }).OrderByDescending(x => x.RegistrationDateTime).ToList();


                    //WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(cardr);

                    //ViewData["cardr"] = cardr;



                    return View(cardr);
                }
```

As you see the view replaces my entire browser. I want to show the error message as a string close to the date box,or something similar to that.

How can I do that?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: If this start date and date are on your view then you can achieve this using jQuery validation either on submit of form or as focus changes from the field.

Comment: Yes my start and the end date are in my view. Can you show me where I can find a sample code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Controller :

```
 public ActionResult List(DateTime startdate, DateTime enddate) 
        {


                List<Card> cards = new List<Card>();

                using (var db = new CardDBEntities())
                {

                    var cardr = (from c in db.Cards
                                 join d in db.RegistrationDTs
                                 on c.CardId equals d.CardId
                                 where d.RegistrationDateTime >= startdate &&
                                       d.RegistrationDateTime <= enddate
                                 select new eReader1.Models.Model
                                 {
                                     CardId = d.CardId,
                                     Description = c.Description,
                                     RegistrationDateTime = d.RegistrationDateTime
                                 }).OrderByDescending(x => x.RegistrationDateTime).ToList();


                    //WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(cardr);

                    //ViewData["cardr"] = cardr;



                    return View(cardr);
                }

            }
```

The view :

```
link href="~/Content/themes/base/minified/jQuery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.min.js"></script>








@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Search criteria</legend>



        @Html.Label("StartDate", "Start Date:")  
         @Html.TextBox("startdate", String.Empty, new { @Class = "startdate" })
        @Html.Label("enddate", "End Date:")
        @Html.TextBox("enddate", String.Empty, new { @Class= "enddate" })



                <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
    </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".startdate").datetimepicker({
            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $(".enddate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
            }
        });

        $(".enddate").datetimepicker({

            dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', timeFormat: 'hh:mm:ss',
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                $(".startdate").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

So I used jQuery plugin for datetimepicker and other jquery ui :

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.datepicker.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js"></script>
<link href="~/Content/themes/base/minified/jQuery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write this kind of function. In this function what you have to do is to  disable dates previous to date in you start date field picker and then show.

```
$('#enddatep').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('.enddate').datepicker('show');
```

});